# How can I count the largest NA data gap for multiple groups in R?

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a data frame (`df1`) where I would like to know the maximum `NA` gap in the `Temp.` column for each unique `siteID`. I have tried to answer this using a for loop but can not get it to work, please see below.

```
df1 <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = 9))
x <- c("siteID", "Date", "Temp.")
colnames(df1) <- x
df1$siteID <- c("a","a","a",
                   "b","b","b",
                   "c","c","c")
df1$Date <- rep(seq(from = as.Date("2020-01-01"), to = as.Date("2020-01-03"), by = 1),3)  
df1$Temp. <- c("10",NA,NA,
               "20",NA,"10",
               "2","4","6")
```

I have tried to answer this by taking a [similar approach to question asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51029171/gap-size-calculation-in-time-series-with-r/51029377?noredirect=1#comment116795919_51029377) @sindri_baldur

```
for(i in 1:length(zz)) {
  res = rle(is.na(df1$Temp.))
  MaxGap = rep(res$values*res$lengths,res$lengths)
  siteID = zz[i]
  if( i == 1){
    saveDat = cbind(MaxGap, siteID)
  } else{
    saveDat = rbind(saveDat, MaxGap)
  }
}
```

The output should look like this

```
saveDat

  siteID MaxGap
1      a      2
2      b      1
3      c      0
```

Comment: Related: [Length of longest stretch of NAs in a column of data-frame object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54501885/length-of-longest-stretch-of-nas-in-a-column-of-data-frame-object)[; Number of consecutive NA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51851215/number-of-consecutive-na)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option where we group by 'siteID' and run-length-id of NA elements of 'Temp.', then create a count column (`n()`), `summarise` to return the `first` value of 'MaxGap' `if` there are `any` `NA` in 'Temp.' or `else` 0, `slice` the max row of 'MaxGap' grouped by 'siteID'

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df1 %>%
   group_by(siteID, grp = rleid(is.na(Temp.))) %>%
   mutate(MaxGap = n()) %>%  
   summarise(MaxGap = if(any(is.na(Temp.))) first(MaxGap)
         else 0, .groups = 'drop') %>%
   group_by(siteID) %>% 
   slice_max(n = 1, MaxGap) %>%
   select(-grp)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
# Groups:   siteID [3]
#  siteID MaxGap
#  <chr>   <dbl>
#1 a           2
#2 b           1
#3 c           0
```

---

Or using `rle`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(siteID) %>%
   summarise(MaxGap = with(rle(is.na(Temp.)),
       max(0, max(lengths[values]))), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  siteID MaxGap
#  <chr>   <dbl>
#1 a           2
#2 b           1
#3 c           0
```